# Why doesn't Firefox on my computer look anything like it does when I see it for download?

Tags: firefox

Somehow when I installed the latest version of Firefox I lost the ablility to input websites that I want to visit.  I don't know the browser very well and I would like help configuring it.

Comment: Holly, please elaborate a little more. How do you mean "lost the ablility to input websites" could you post a screenshot to help us diagnose the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Right-click on the menu bar and enable the Navigation Toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

If you're missing the address bar (where one types website names), try VIEW > TOOLBARS > NAVIGATION TOOLBAR should be checked.

This is for the 3.x versions.

What version of Firefox are you using?

The latest stable one is v3.6.15 but the newer Firefox 4 will be released very shortly.

Comment: A shortcut if the menus are not there is:  ALT-V then T then N